# Updating One Form After Event Occurs in Another Form

Tags: c#, winforms, message

I am struggling to determine the best way to update one form based on an event that occurs in another.

For example, my application has a form that displays a list of parts (i.e. inventory, non-inventory, etc...) in a `ListView`.  My application also has a form that allows the user to add a new part.  The application is not a `MDI`.

What are my best options for updating the form that displays the list of parts every time an item is inserted, updated, or deleted from the other form?

I realize that I could pass a reference into the second form in cases where the form is instantiated from the first but, I'd prefer not to tightly couple the forms.  I have experimented with custom events but, I think that is going to require implementation of a class in the middle that takes over instantiation of the forms so that it has access to both objects.

I guess I could use .NET built in properties.  What are my best options?

Comment: Best to show your current code so that one can see / follow your logically thinking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we're just talking about two forms I would go the simple route (e.g. Don't use a factory class).

in your receiver form add an event (like `ProductListChanged`)

add a global variable (via static class property (see below)) to hold the receiver form.

```
public class globals {
  public static ProductForm productForm {get;set;}
}
```

Then you can raise the ProductListChanged event via the global static property.

Comment: Okay, this sounds like a much simpler solution.  So, just to make sure I correctly understand...The ProductForm (i.e. receiver) would both define the event and handle it.  Then, the sender(s) (i.e. AddItemForm, UpdateItemForm, etc...) would fire the ProductListChanged event on the ProductForm reference in the static class and the ProductForm would handle the event?  Sorry for being such a noob...

Comment: @Grasshopper: we're all students.  And you got it correct - yes.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me as I worked through understanding events.  Most of the projects I've worked on in the past have had one or more architects and senior folks in their respective disciplines to help with design especially layering areas of concern.  This project is the first where I am the DBA, Architect, System Analyst, Business Analyst, Support Tech, UAT, etc....While frustrating at times, it has definitely helped me grow.  This site and others has been a big help since I don't have the resources within the company to ask for help and/or advice.

Comment: @Grasshopper: This site is a huge resource for me as well.  It is certainly frustrating being the only developer at a company.  If you need/want to chat outside of stack-o, you can catch me on google chat at danwalker.ak @ gmail