# Trigger event from window1 to main window c#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Updating One Form After Event Occurs in Another Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470150/updating-one-form-after-event-occurs-in-another-form)

Relevant info: Using WPF Application, C#, Visual Studio 2010, .Net 4

I have two windows: Window1 and MainWindow.  In Window1 I have a checkbox, that when checked, will set a label1 in MainWindow to not visible.  How would I go about this?

I can't do `MainWindow newWindow = new MainWindow()` because I'm not trying to make a new main window.  I tried the following code but I get a exception thrown: {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}`.

```
private void checkBox4_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (checkBox4.IsChecked == true)
   {
       (Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow).label1.Visibility = 
                   Visibility.Hidden;
   }
   else
   {
       (Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow).label1.Visibility = 
                   Visibility.Visible;
   }
}
```

What would be the best way to go about this?  Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an event to `Window1`:

```
public event Action<bool> SomethingChecked; //TODO rename to indicate what was checked
```

When the checkbox is checked raise that event:

```
private void checkBox4_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(SomethingChecked != null)
        SomethingChecked(checkBox4.IsChecked);
}
```

Then add an event handler from the main form:

```
Window1 other = new Window1();
other.SomethingChecked += checked => label1.Visibility = 
    checked ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
```

Comment: I just started with that suggestion, yours is better laid out :)

Comment: Where do I put the code for "Then add an event handler from the main form:" in my MainFunction?  I just let it float in my MainWindow class?  I have my Window1 globally declared, so I guess I'm asking, where do I stick 

`other.SomethingChecked += checked => label1.Visibility = 
    checked ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;`

Comment: Since Window1 is globally declared, I am assuming there is a global instance of Window1 available. You can declare the event handler in MainWindow Load method.

Comment: @Baddack You should probably add the event handler right after you create the instance of the child form.  `my Window1 globally declared` you really shouldn't do that.  You should always keep your variables scoped as narrowly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Create an event in Window1, handle that event in MainWindow.

Just an example below, not really a working code...

```
MainWindow
{
    private void SomeStuff()
    {
        Window1 window = new Window1();
        window.CheckBoxClick += new OnCheckBoxClick(SomeMethod);
    }

    private void SomeMethod(bool state)
    {
         // use state;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) you have not shown how to define an event 2) your syntax for assigning an event handler is wrong.

Comment: Oops yes... I din't realize my "not really a working code" will not work at all >.<

Comment: using `new OnCheckBoxClick` is not needed; the compiler will infer the delegate type based on whatever you declare the event as.